# Infinite while loop C++

Tags: c++, while-loop, infinite-loop

I was trying to implement a solution for palindrome, I think my logic is correct, but my program gets stuck in an infinite loop and I get an error message of "Prep.exe has stopped working"

```
int main()
{
    string word, reverse;

    cout << "Please enter a word to test for palindrome : ";
    cin >> word;
    cout << "Your word is: "<< word << endl;

    int i = 0;
    int size = word.length() - 1;
    while (size >= 0)
    {
        reverse[i++] = word[size--];
        //cout << reverse[i++];
    }

    cout << "The reversed word is: " << reverse << endl;


    if (word == reverse)
        cout << "It is palindrome" << endl;
    else
        cout << "It is not a palindrome" << endl;
}
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong with my while loop. I keep on decrementing it and and I have a valid exit condition, so why does it get stuck in a loop?

Comment: have you tried outputing `size` before the loop? if for whatever reason it is 0, the while will never terminate.

Comment: What is the output when you uncomment `//cout << reverse[i++]`?  You may want to change it to `cout << reverse[i - 1]`

Comment: It doesn't show a result, it goes straight to say "its not a palindrome"

Comment: This is wrong: `reverse[i++]`  You can't just write to arbitrary positions, the index needs to be *within* the string, and no bounds checking is performed for you.  You're writing into memory you don't "own", which results in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not getting an infinite loop; you're getting a crash due to an Out Of Bounds access in the line `reverse[i++]` because `reverse` is an empty string. Try using the `reverse.push_back()` function instead.

Comment: Which library is .append() part of?

Comment: I think `push_back()` would be more appropriate than `append()`. There isn't a single-char overload for `append()`.

Comment: it is a sting method (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/). Actually, don't even use append, use `string reverse(word.rbegin(), word.rend());` and get rid of the loop :P (ok not really the point is it)

Comment: Is it bad to compare 2 strings like if(reverse[i]!= word[i]) check = false;

Answer (score 0):

did you initialize the variable reverse 
just check that and try after initializing it.

hope that works